# Symfony2: Always return a variable to TWIG

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

- I've created a User entity, which implements UserInterface. Everything it's ok.
- I've created two auxiliar tables, managing roles and permissions (each role has some permissions).

So, my entities are:

**User** -> has one role (one role, and this role comes from--->)

**Role** -> just the name of the role

**Permission** -> just the name of the permission

**RolePermission** -> creates a relation between a role and permissions.

What I need to do is get the permissions the current logged user have: how to this? Looking first for the role of the user, and looking in RolePermission which permissions have.

This is ok, but once I have this permissions I need to send it to TWIG.

I can do this manually, sending on every `$this->render` of the app an array those permissions, but I think is not the best solution (lazy...).

Is possible to send this data (an array with the permissions) every time I render a TWIG template? How?

EDIT:

This question is about getting info associated with the logged user, but not about to check the role in TWIG (is_granted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of research, and because of my needs I'm finally returning and array with the permissions in every `->render`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a database schema like this...

```
[table User] --ManyToOne--> [table Role] --OneToMany--> [table Permission]
```

...you can try the following:

```
{% for permission in app.user.role.permissions %}
    {{ permission.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It looks like the solution. I'll check and then come back to approve it :)

Answer (score 0):

In Twig, use the [`is_granted()`](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/security.html#access-control-in-templates) function to check if the current user has a specific role:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
    {# output stuff for an admin #}
{% endif %}
```

---

If you want to get the roles of the current user, do this:

```
{% for role in app.user.roles %}
    {# do what you want with the role #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: As I said, I don't need this . I've already know how to get the check the role in twig...

Comment: This question is about getting info associated with the logged user, (an array with the permissions, where permissions is another entity) but not about to check the role in TWIG (is_granted)

Comment: No, I've edited again the question. Is more clear? Thanks for the help ;=)